# SortedList C++ delete and undelete elements from the array

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, sortedlist

How to restore elements of the array that i already deleted ? it's a

```
template<class genType, int MAX_ITEMS >
void SortedList<genType, MAX_ITEMS>::DeleteItem(genType item) {
    bool found = false;
    int location = 0;
    for (; location<length && !found; location++)
        if (item == items[location])
            found = true;
    if (found) {
        for (int index = location; index < length; index++)
            items[index - 1] = items[index];
        length--;
    }
}
```

Sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to restore elements to an array you would simply need to store all removed elements in a separate data structure, pre-removal.

To do this, add the following to your code:

```
if (found) {
    deletedArray[dIter] = items[location];
    dIter++;

    for (int index = location; index < length; index++)
        items[index - 1] = items[index];
    length--;
}
```

Now, if you want to restore these deleted elements to the array at a later time, you can do something like this:

```
void restoreDeleted() {
    for (int i = 0; i < dIter; i++) 
       insert(deletedArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Edited for further clarification.